# Which fundamental force is responsible for the Casimir effect?

Tags: forces, casimir-effect

I've read about the [Casimir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect), and there seem to be no particle mediating the force; but the virtual particles called virtual photons. Is it enough to conclude that the Casimir effect is due to the electroweak [fundamental force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction)?

Edit regarding the tag as duplicate question. In the link given, one reads

> (...) Casimir forces can be computed without reference to zero point
>   energies. They are relativistic, quantum forces between charges and
>   currents.

My question still remains the same: Is it enough to conclude that the Casimir effect is due to the electroweak fundamental force? If yes, then there is no particle mediating this force?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the relationship between the dynamical casimir effect and virtual particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30003/)

Answer (score 3):

It is to do with energy density of the vacuum. As a property of space, that would seem likely to be linked to gravity, and quantisation of space-time. But given no one knows how to do quantum gravity, we don't know yet.

Comment: The greatest margin of error in physics is the absolute difference in the vacuum density expected from quantum theory and the vacuum density expected from the cosmological constant. The error has a magnitude of 10^120!